# Using two same column information, combine third column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A  B  C
1  1  2
1  1  3
4  4  5
```

And desire output should look like this:

```
A  B  C
1  1  2,3
4  4  5
```

I want to do it by using python pandas but haven't solve how can I do. I'll be happy if you help. Thanks!

Comment: You are expected  to add the data as text, we can not copy the contents from the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `astype()`+`groupby()`+`agg()`:

```
df=df.astype({'C':'str'}).groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False)['C'].agg(','.join)
#OR
df=df.astype({'C':'str'}).groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False).agg({'C':','.join})
```

output:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   1   2,3
1   4   4   5
```